# Получение CRC-16 из массива байт

Tags: hex

Из мануала к COM устройству есть пример:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

, где 2 последних байта рассчитываются как CRC-16 первых байтов с полиномом X16-X15-X2-1 и инициализации 0xFFFF.

пользуясь [онлайн калькулятором](http://www.scadacore.com/field-applications/programming-calculators/online-checksum-calculator/) подсчета crc-16 сумм я не смог добиться этих значений. Грешу на мануал, но все алгоритмы найденные здесь дают разные результаты...

Comment: Здесь, похоже, используется crc16 без финального `result = result XOR 0xFFFF`. Либо (если исходники под вашим контролем) уберите эту операцию, либо наоборот, после подсчёта crc16 проксорьте результат с 0x0FFFF. Получите именно то, что на картинке.

Comment: К сожалению это сторонний девайс, есть только описание

Comment: Так а в чём вопрос тогда?

Comment: Я долблюсь уже сутки и не понимаю, либо кривой мануал, либо кривой я.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всё абсолютно стандартно:

```
#include <stdio.h>

static unsigned short crc_16_table[256];

static void make_crc16_table(void) {
    unsigned short r, i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
        r = ((unsigned short) i) << 8;
        for (j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
            if (r & (1 << 15))
                r = (r << 1) ^ 0x8005;
            else
                r = r << 1;
        }
        crc_16_table[i] = r;
    }
}

static unsigned short crc16(const char *buf, size_t len) {
    unsigned short crc = 0xFFFF;
    while (len--) {
        crc = crc_16_table[((crc >> 8) ^ *buf++) & 0xFF] ^ (crc << 8);
    }
    return crc;
}

int main() {
    make_crc16_table();
    return printf("%X\n", crc16("\x80\x01\x0C", 3)) == 1;
}
```

Comment: Камрад! Ты сделал мой день!!!